# access 2003 cycle current page not working if subform is in form view

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, subform

I have a form with multiple sub-forms.
I would like to have the following behaviour: pressing the tab key in the last field of the main form or in the last field of a subform the focus moves to the next subform or back to the main form according to the defined *Tab order*.
To achieve this, all subforms as well as the main form have the *Cycle* property set to *Current page*.
All subforms are shown within the main form as Datasheets except one that is shown in *Form view*.
Now I get the behaviour I want only for the main form and for the subforms shown as datasheets but not for the subform shown as *Form*.
Is this the normal behaviour in access 2003, of is there some other property that I have to change?
**Note**: if I change the default view of the "misbehaving" form to *Datasheet* as the others, it also behaves as I want...
What am I doing wrong?
And... if this is the way access 2003 works... what would be the best way to obtain the desired behaviour using vba given that I cannot find an OnTab method?
**Edit:** While waiting to understand if this can be done setting the right properties in the forms, I acheved the desired behaviour with this code in the first and last fields of the "misbehaving" subform.

```
'In the last field
Private Sub Posizione_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If (KeyCode = vbKeyTab And Shift = 0) Then
        KeyCode = 0
        Me.Parent!Autore_Subform.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

'in the first field
Private Sub Stanza_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If (KeyCode = vbKeyTab And Shift = 1) Then
        KeyCode = 0
        Me.Parent!Pagine.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In access 2.0 I used an extra control at the end and start of a form (and subform) and have code in the OnEnter event of those controls to direct focus to the correct control. I expect this trick to work in Access2003 as well.

Comment: Its the standard behaviour because the subform is in form view. Use rene's approach.

Comment: I have had the same problem and I also solved it using code to setfocus to the correct control at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for an answer to the same question, and found [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/move-between-a-main-form-and-a-subform-in-form-view-HP005187820.aspx) via Google: Ctrl-Tab will move from the last control in the subform to the next control in the main form.  I found from experimenting (with Access 2007) that it doesn't matter which control has focus in the subform, Ctrl-Tab will pop you out of the subform to the next control in the main form.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but indeed, the only solution to my issue is the code. One I added works just fine.